# JSON.parse from a URL

Tags: json, reactjs

I have several URL similar to https://zkillboard.com/api/stats/solarSystemID/31000007/
I am trying to extract the JSON from the url into an object.

I have been able to get as far as this which returns a Promise, PromiseState: fulfilled and PromiseResults contains an object with the data I am looking for.

```
  async function readJSON(url:string) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open ('get', url, false)
    request.send(null)
    if (request.status == 200) {
      return JSON.parse(request.responseText)
    }
  }
  const systemJSON = readJSON('https://zkillboard.com/api/stats/solarSystemID/31000007/')

  console.log(systemJSON)
```

How can I ensure that my console.log only returns the PromiseResult?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have fixed it for me, removed the async from the function as well as `.responseText` in the `JSON.parse()`

```
  function readJSON(url:string) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open ('get', url, false)
    request.send(null)
    if (request.status == 200) {
      return JSON.parse(request.response)
    }
  }
  
  const systemJSON = readJSON('https://zkillboard.com/api/stats/solarSystemID/31000007/')
  
  const printJSON = () =>{
    console.log(systemJSON)
  }

  printJSON();
```

Answer (score -1):

First off, when handling json from an external source I would suggest wrapping it in a try/catch function, to avoid unsuspecting errors.

Secondly I think the issue is that readJSON returns a promise, so you might need to await it.

```
try {
   const json = await readJSON('https://zkillboard.com/api/stats/solarSystemID/31000007/')
   const systemJSON = JSON.parse(json);
} catch (error) {
   // Woops something happend - see error variable
}
```